# The requested service has not been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

I am trying to call my repository and I am getting the following Autofac error:

> The requested service 'DOL.DTLLicense.DataAccess.Repositories.ApplicationTypeRepository' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

I am guessing there is something wrong in my IocConfig, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I'm binding my repositories.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my IocConfig:

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register MVC Controllers
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        // Bind all repositories to Ef repos (entity framework)
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DataAccess.Repositories.ApplicationRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(repo => repo.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .WithParameter("connectionstring", Environment.MachineName)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf();

        // Unit of Work
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ApplicationBusiness).Assembly)
            .Where(b => b.Name.EndsWith("Business"))                
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationViewModelBuilder>().As<IApplicationViewModelBuilder>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationCommand>().As<IApplicationCommand>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Enable property injection into action filters
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
    }
```

ViewModelBuilder:

```
public class ApplicationViewModelBuilder : IApplicationViewModelBuilder
{
    private readonly IApplicationBusiness _applicationBusiness;
    private readonly IApplicationTypeBusiness _applicationTypeBusiness;

    public ApplicationViewModelBuilder(IApplicationBusiness applicationBusiness, IApplicationTypeBusiness applicationTypeBusiness)
    {
        _applicationBusiness = applicationBusiness;
        _applicationTypeBusiness = applicationTypeBusiness;
    }

    public ApplicationApplyNowViewModel BuildApplyNow()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> applicationTypes = SetApplicationTypesDropdown();
        var vm = new ApplicationApplyNowViewModel(applicationTypes);

        return vm;
    }
}
```

Service Layer:

```
public class ApplicationTypeBusiness : BusinessBase, IApplicationTypeBusiness
{
    private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ApplicationTypeBusiness).FullName);

    private readonly IApplicationTypeRepository applicationTypeRepository;

    public ApplicationTypeBusiness(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        applicationTypeRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<ApplicationTypeRepository>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ApplicationType> GetAll()
    {
        return applicationTypeRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public ApplicationType GetApplicationType(int applicationTypeId)
    {
        return applicationTypeRepository.GetApplicationType(applicationTypeId);
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SqlContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork() : this(new SqlContext()) { }

    public UnitOfWork(SqlContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T GetRepository<T>() where T : class
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var result = scope.Resolve<T>(new NamedParameter("context", _context));

            if (result != null && result.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICompanyRepository)))
                return result;
        }

        return null;   
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        _context
            .ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Reload());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your UnitOfWork is creating a new container instead of using the existing container.  It would be better if you injected an `IComponentContext` and resolved from there.  You're also resolving from a lifetime scope which ends before the object is finished being used.  Using an object past its scope might result in the container attempting to garbage collect the object.

Comment: @Amy Thank you, could you show me an example?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your `T GetRepository<T>() where T : class` method is the service locator anti-pattern.

Comment: Would you recommend not doing it that way?  I was looking at this article: http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/a-better-entity-framework-unit-of-work-pattern-DD

Comment: It's generally better, if using DI, to directly inject the repository where its needed.  Sometimes this isn't doable though, and the service locator is necessary.  I can't speak to whether that's the case here.  I'll also add that not everyone agrees the service locator is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a private field to your `UnitOfWork`:

```
private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;
```

Inject it into your constructor:

```
public UnitOfWork(SqlContext context, IComponentContext componentContext)
{
    _context = context;
    _componentContext = componentContext;
}
```

Then resolve from that:

```
public T GetRepository<T>() where T : class
{
    var result = _componentContext.Resolve<T>(new NamedParameter("context", _context));
    if (result != null && result.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICompanyRepository)))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return null;   
}
```

Comment: Do I need to update this line also? `public UnitOfWork() : this(new SqlContext()) { }`

Comment: Yeah.  Null to the second argument.  Though if the unit of work is instantiated using this constructor, you won't be able to resolve components.  Which should be fine, Autofac will pick the constructor it has the arguments for, in your case, the one that accepts an `IComponentContext`

Comment: I think we're close.  I get a runtime error and it says the value cannot be null.  Parameter name: context.  Is there anything I need to change in the IocConfig?

Comment: What did you change the constructor signature to?  It should be `UnitOfWork() : this(new SqlContext(), null) { ... }`

Comment: That's what I have `public UnitOfWork() : this(new SqlContext(), null) { }`

Comment: Where is the error being thrown?  Where you attempt to resolve a repository?

Comment: The `SqlContext` isn't registered with the container, so Autofac won't select that constructor overload.

Comment: It looks like this line `applicationTypeRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<ApplicationTypeRepository>();`

Comment: Should I add something like this then? `builder.RegisterType<SqlContext>()
           .As<IUnitOfWork>()
           .InstancePerRequest();`

Comment: I changed the parameter to just accept the `IComponentContext` and inside there I set `_context = new SqlContext()`.  Now it's saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  What should I add to the `IocConfig` so I can inject the `IComponentContext`?

Comment: Shouldn't need to register anything at all.  `IComponentContext` is provided by Autofac automatically.  The answer has been marked as accepted.  I guess everything's working for you now?

Comment: No, I never got it working.  You helped out a lot though so I wanted to give you the points.  I just changed the `UnitOfWork` class to look like this instead: `public IApplicationTypeRepository ApplicationTypeRepository
        {
            get { return _applicationTypeRepository ?? (_applicationTypeRepository = new ApplicationTypeRepository(_context)); }
        }`